# Updating A Small Application

Tags: c#, download

I've made a small application for fun and I want to implement an update feature.

I don't really have a remote server or anything. I thought I could use a file hosting site to host my application. So :

1. Does anyone know a good site which I can easily download files from? (not like rapidshare that you have to wait. more like a direct link.)
2. How can I make the application check if there is an update.

DONT link me to CLICK-ONCE, it seems way too complex for my needs. I just need a creative solution so that my program can ask : "update available?, if yes, give me the link".

Comment: I dont think this is related to C# programming, did you invest sometime in researching about this before questioning here?

Comment: All the solutions I saw were related to clickonce, maybe someone knows another way?. (the fact I don't need code, doesn't mean its not related to programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Amazon Web Services S3 and CloudFront to host your application files. If you don't want to use ClickOnce, you could simply have the application download a text file that has the latest version number from a predefined update site. Have your program compare it with the current running version and if there is a new version available pop-up a message with a link to download the new installer.
Whenever you have a new version, simply upload your new installer and update the version text file with the new version number.

Comment: P-e-r-f-e-c-t. That's the kind of solution I was looking for.

Comment: Almost... You need to pay to amazon (their free plan is a mess).